# List Plot Error

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, warning-messages

I've produced this simulation of a superhetrodyne radio receiver. I'm pretty sure it's solid for the most part but I'm getting a list plot error.

> ListPlot::lpn: {{{1.,0.},{2.,0.00104953},{3.,0.00417391},{4.,0.00897666},{5.,0.0144962},{6.,0.019545},{7.,0.0231284},{8.,0.0247955},{9.,0.0247967},{10.,0.0239932},<<31>>,{42.,0.0875546},{43.,0.0860275},{44.,0.0862261},{45.,0.0881567},{46.,0.091152},{47.,0.0941063},{48.,0.0958663},{49.,0.0956389},{50.,0.0932715},<<385951>>},<<3>>,{}} is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers.

I'm having a total nightmare trying to make sense where my mistake is. Any help would be appreciated.

Code below. Thank you.

```
f1 = 87500000;
f2 = 92000000;
f3 = 965000000;
f4 = 101000000;

sf = 10000;
if = 10700000;
m = 1;

stationselect = f1;


Flo = stationselect + if;

nyquist = 1/(2*Max[{f1, f2, f3, f4}]);
nyquist

timerange = 2/sf;

Clear[sig];  sig [t_, f_] := Sin[2 \[Pi]*f*t];

tone1 = Table[sig[t, {sf*1.0}], {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];
tone2 = Table[sig[t, {sf*1.2}], {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];
tone3 = Table[sig[t, {sf*1.4}], {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];
tone4 = Table[sig[t, {sf*1.6}], {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];


(*transmitting*)

data = Table[
     Sin[2 \[Pi]*f1*t + m*(Cos[t*2 \[Pi]*sf*1.0])] + 
    Sin[2 \[Pi]*f1*t + m*(Cos[t*2 \[Pi]*sf*1.2])] + 
    Sin[2 \[Pi]*f1*t + m*(Cos[t*2 \[Pi]*sf*1.4])] +
    Sin[2 \[Pi]*f1*t + m*(Cos[t*2 \[Pi]*sf*1.6])],
   {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];

(* filtering*)

rec = data*Table[sig[t, Flo], {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];

filter1 = ButterworthFilterModel [{"Bandpass", 1, {{2 \[Pi]*if, 40}}}];
filter2 = ButterworthFilterModel [{"Bandpass", 3, {{2 \[Pi]*if, 20}}}];
filter3 = ButterworthFilterModel [{"Bandpass", 5, {{2 \[Pi]*if, 10}}}];

filtered1 = 
  2* RecurrenceFilter[ToDiscreteTimeModel[filter1, nyquist], rec];
filtered2 = 
  2* RecurrenceFilter[ToDiscreteTimeModel[filter1, nyquist], rec];
filtered3 = 
  2* RecurrenceFilter[ToDiscreteTimeModel[filter1, nyquist], rec];


(*Define function*)
Clear[fourierPlot];

fourierPlot[s_] := 
  Transpose[{Range[0, 0.5/nyquist, 
     0.5/(nyquist * (Length[Abs[Fourier[s]]] - 1))], Abs[Fourier[s]]}];

(*display*)
Framed[
 Column[{
   Style["Filtered signal", "section"],
   
   (*signal plot*)
   Framed[ 
    ListPlot[{filtered1, tone1, tone2, tone3, 
      tone4}, (*plot chosen filtered signal*)
     PlotLabel -> 
      Style["Time domain plot of filtered FM signal2", 
       "Subsubsection"],
     Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{5000, 15000}, Full}, 
     ImageSize -> {Full, Medium},(*Zoom/
     format plot to make FM signal easier to see*) 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[LineLegend[
        Automatic, {"Filtered FM signal", "Station 1 tone", 
         "Station 2 tone", "Station 3 tone", 
         "Station 4 tone"}, (*Define legends*) 
        LabelStyle -> Bold, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Bottom]]],
   
   GraphicsRow[{
     Framed[BodePlot[
       {filter1, filter2, filter3},
       {100, 300000000}, PlotRange -> Full, 
       PlotLayout -> "Magnitude",(*Define plot domain*)
       PlotLegends -> 
        Placed[LineLegend[
          Automatic, {"Filter 1st order", "Filter 3rd order", 
           "Filter 5th order"}, LabelStyle -> Bold], 
         Bottom], (*legend underneath*)
       FrameLabel -> {"frequency/Hz", "signal Magnitude/dB"}
       ]],
     
     (*fourier transforms*)
     Manipulate[
      ListPlot[
       Evaluate[
        FunctionDisplay /. {1 -> fourierPlot[rec], 
          2 -> fourierPlot[filtered1], 3 -> fourierPlot[filtered2], 
          4 -> fourierPlot[filtered3]}],
       Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
       PlotLabel -> Style["FFT or Signals", "Subsubsection"], 
       Ticks -> {Join[
          Table[{i*10^7, ScientificForm[i*10^7]}, {i, 0., 12., 1.}]], 
         Automatic},
       PlotStyle -> {
          
          Directive[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[5]], Opacity[0.8], 
           Thin],
          ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]],
          ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]],
          ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[3]]
          }[[FunctionDisplay]], 
       
       PlotLegends -> 
        Placed[LineLegend[
          Automatic, {"mixed signal (rec)", "1st order filter", 
            "3rd order filter", "5th order filter"}[[
           FunctionDisplay]], 
          LabelStyle -> Bold, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Bottom],
       FrameLabel -> {"Frequency/Hz", "Amplitude/V"}
       ],
      {{FunctionDisplay, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {1 -> "Mixed Signal", 
        2 -> "1st Order Filter", 3 -> "3rd Order Filter", 
        4 -> "5th Order Filter"}, CheckboxBar},
      ControlPlacement -> Bottom, FrameMargins -> None
      ]
     }, ImageSize -> Full] 
   }, Alignment -> Center],
 FrameMargins -> Automatic]
```

Comment: The "tones" are not flattened: ListPlot[Map[Flatten, {filtered1, tone1, tone2, tone3, tone4}]

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2158150).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the curly brackets {} in {sf*1.0} etc., to yield:

```
tone1 = Table[sig[t, sf*1.0], {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];
tone2 = Table[sig[t, sf*1.2], {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];
tone3 = Table[sig[t, sf*1.4], {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];
tone4 = Table[sig[t, sf*1.6], {t, 0, timerange, nyquist}];
```